# Stopping Avecto Defendpoint programmatically

Tags: powershell

Before anyone says anything about access rights...
I have full access to services and can manually stop both the Avecto Defendpoint Service and the Avecto Defendpoint ePO Interface. And, all users who will be using this application will also have admin rights.

Im trying to find a way to stop the Avecto Defendpoint service through PowerShell. I've tried...

Right-click on PowerShell (Run as admin)

```
Stop-Service -Name "Avecto Defendpoint Service"
```

With this as a response...

```
Stop-Service : Service 'Avecto Defendpoint Service (Avecto Defendpoint
Service)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open Avecto
Defendpoint Service service on computer '.'.
```

I've also tried using the -Force parameter with the same result. If I manually disable Avecto prior to running the PowerShell I can manually start the service back up again and THEN I can kill it as intended from the PowerShell; but this defeats the purpose of embedding the functionality into the program.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Absolutely nothing! I removed the tag. The program that this will be embedded in is written in Java, but for this question that fact is inconsequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to stop Defendpoint from working:

```
Stop-Service -InputObject "Avecto Defendpoint Service" -Force
```

Once you are finished and need to re-enable it, use this:

```
Start-Service -InputObject "Avecto Defendpoint Service"
```

Comment: Will this log anything to the IT administrator? Will they get a notification that a PowerShell prompt has stopped the service? I assume Avecto Defendpoint has a controller somewhere to manage the policies, or is it a completely standalone application?

Comment: If  Avecto has been correctly configured, you will still not have the privilege to stop Avecto with the -Force flag.   I executed the above command running Powershell as Administrator and I still get the same error.

In my company this would be a violation that could bring about disciplinary action, including termination of employment ( most likely only if the attempts were repeated after warnings).

My advice is to work on a business reason, approach your IT security department, present your case and ask for a work around / solution.